Armorer 'Armor Modifications' and enhanced defense
The level 9 Armorer artificer's 'Armor Modifications' allows for an additional two infusions on your armor, but also splits the armor into multiple pieces (head, chest, boots and special weapon). could I apply enhanced defense on the helmet to preserve propulsion armor on the chest, and enhanced weapon on the special weapon? The main question here Is about the enhanced defense and helmet comparability, but I notice that propulsion armor applies to so many aspects of the original suit that once each piece is deemed separate it starts to feel weird.
